# I need to take 500 screenshots at 325x200 over and over. How can I do this on a Mac quickly?

Tags: macos, mac, screen-capture

I could just do Cmd-Shift-4 and draw them out, but that would take forever and kill my hand doing that 500 times.

Is there a screenshot app/utility out there for Mac that would allow me to set a specific size of a fixed box and just allow me to quickly take screenshots over and over just moving the box around on the screen?

Comment: Did you succeed? What was the trigger (if any) ?

Comment: I'm sure imagemagick (from homebrew) plus some scripting could be a candidate.

Answer (score 2):

If you know javascript you could use something like phantom.js feed it a list of urls to get screen captures

http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html

Comment: Images aren't from a URL. They are embedded in a Numbers spreadsheet.

Comment: think you'll be pretty hard pressed to find an app to do that, but good luck